# CPA in assembly language. How CPA and Accumulator works?

Tags: pep8-assembly

According to the book ,
In the assembly language, opcode CPA compares the operand in the memory and the data in the accumulator.
I want to know how the instruction CPA affects A register(accumulator)

```
BR main 

NUM1: .block 2

NUM2: .block 2

MSG1: .ascii “A register is less than 0\0x00”

MSG2: .asciiA register is more than 0\0x00”

Compared: .block2 

main: 

      DECI NUM1,d.    ; for example, 1

      DECI NUM2,d.          ; for example, 4

      LDA NUM1,d

      CPA NUM2,d.      ;after comparing num1(which is now in - 
                    -Accumulator) and num 2(in the memory)


      STA Compared,d.  ;if i store the contents in the Accumulator,
                  Whih figure would accumulator have? 3 or 2?


      BRlT lessThan 
      BR   End

LessThan: 

      STRO msg1,d

      DECO compared,d

          BR END


END: 

      stop 

      .End
```

#

According to PEP/8 simulator,
The result was “the register is less than 0”, while the accululator is still 1.

What happens when using CPA? Please help me ((

Comment: Comparison is comparison, it doesn’t change the register.

Comment: Then the book Computer Science Illuminated 6th edition might be wrong because it says ‘Mnemonic BRLT means ‘Set the Program Counter to thre operand if the Accumulator is less than zero’

Comment: #Sami Kuhmonen, and thank you for your quick response))